# How can a character pointer without any address specification hold data?

Tags: c, string, pointers, char, string-literals

The following C program is not supposed to work by my understanding of pointers but it does.

```
#include<stdio.h>
main() {
    char *p;
    p = "abcdefghijk";
    printf("%s", p);
}
```

Outputs:

> abcdefghijk

The char pointer variable `p` is pointing to something random as I have not assigned any address to it like `p = &i;` where `i` is some char array.

That means if I try to write anything to the memory address held by the pointer `p` it should give me segmentation fault since it is some random address not assigned to my program by the OS.

But the program compiles and runs successfully. What is happening?

Comment: actually the pointer has an adress it's just the data it points to is not set. you say to your compiler : here is a pointer on a char i name it p, then you say now i want my pointer to point on this string. there is nothing invalid in that it's just cleaner to affect it sraight away. in the other hand if you try to read the value of p before affecting it you'll get your segfault (if you compile in release)

Comment: oh god it was such a retarded question.I should get tested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C a string literal like `"abcdefghijk"` is actually stored as an (read-only) array of characters. The assignment makes `p` point to the first character of that array.

---

I note that you mention `p = &i` where `i` would be an array. That is in most cases wrong. Arrays naturally decays to pointers to their first element. I.e. doing `p = i` would be equal to `p = &i[0]`.

While both `&i` and `&i[0]` would result in the same address, it is semantically very different. Lets take an example:

```
char array[10];
```

With the above definition doing `&array[0]` (or just plain `array` as explained just above) you get a pointer to `char`, i.e. `char *`. When doing `&array` you get a pointer to an array of ten characters, i.e. `char (*)[10]`. The two types are very different.

Comment: @JeremyP Yes, literal strings in C are read-only. They may not be *constant* but definitely read-only. It's allowed to use non-constant pointers to them (it's forbidden in C++) but you may not modify a string literal and attempting to do so will lead to *undefined behavior*. Ergo read-only. :)

Comment: No. 6.4.5 point 7: "if the program attempts to modify such an array [the array of chars created by the compiler to represent the litera], the behaviour is undefined". Therefore the literal is not necessarily read only. Writing to it may or may not work.

Comment: @JeremyP Let me rephrase it: It is *in practice* "read-only". Like I said, it's not *constant* but should be *treated* as it were. We are both saying the same thing, just using different phrasing.

Comment: No it is not "in practice read only". It is "in practice read only" on the most popular architectures with the most popular compilers/linkers. If your architecture has no memory protection or the compiler/linker doesn't make the segment the string is in read only, then you can write to it. This is why the standard says undefined behaviour because there is no way to guarantee read only without making assumptions about the platform on which the executable will be running.

Comment: Incidentally, this was a problem for early (pre Ansi) compilers. The view was often taken that you *should* be able to write to such strings which meant you couldn't put them in the text segment and you couldn't intern string constants.

Comment: @JeremyP What architecture or toolchain does is irrelevant. Standard says that if you write to literal, you get undefined behaviour. That is "in practice read only". If any enviroment allows to do otherwise, it is no longer what we know to be standard C, and not within scope of this question.

Comment: @user694733 No, it's not "in practice read only", it's undefined behaviour. If it were read only, the behaviour would not be undefined.

Comment: @JeremyP What is the point you are trying to make? Everybody knows it's undefined behaviour. Point of this answer's "read-only" bit is (presumably) to tell to (presumably) beginner to avoid writing literals. It may be a small simplification, but serves to make answer easier to read.

Comment: @user694733 That undefined behaviour is not necessarily read only. He could have simplified it by saying "writing to the string is undefined behaviour, so don't do it". Just as simple but not lying.

Answer (score 4):

In this expression statement

```
p="abcdefghijk";
```

the pointer `p` is assigned with the address of the first character of the string literal `"abcdefghijk"` that the compiler stores as a zero-terminated character array in the static memory area.

Thus in this statement there are two things that happen. At first the compiler creates an unnamed character array with the static storage duration to hold the string literal. Then the address of the first character of the array is assigned to the pointer. You can imagine it the following way

```
char unnamed[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', '\0' };
p = unnamed;
```

or

```
p = &unnamed[0];
```

Take into account that though string literals in C have types of non-constant character arrays opposite to C++ where they have types of constant character arrays nevertheless you may not change string literals. Any attempt to change a string literal results in undefined behavior.

So this code snippet is invalid

```
char *p = "abcdefghijk";
p[0] = 'A';
```

But you could create your own character array initializing it with the string literal and in this case you can change the array. For example

```
char s[] = "abcdefghijk";
char *p = s;
p[0] = 'A';
```

From the C Standard (6.4.5 String literals)

> 7 It is unspeciﬁed whether these arrays are distinct provided their
>   elements have the appropriate values. If the program attempts to
>   modify such an array, the behavior is undeﬁned.

Pay attention to this part of the quote

> It is unspeciﬁed whether these arrays are distinct provided their 
>   elements have the appropriate values.

It means that for example if you will write

```
char *p = "abcdefghijk";
char *q = "abcdefghijk";
```

then it is not necessary that this expression yields true (integer value 1)

```
p == q
```

and the result depends on compiler options whether the same string literals are stored as one array or as distinct arrays.

Answer (score 0):

`p="abcdefghijk";`

You are creating a string literal in code segment and assigning the address of first character of the literal to the pointer, and as the pointer is not constant you can assign it again with different addresses.

Answer (score 0):

The string literal `"abcdefghijk"` is compiled by putting the characters in a block in the program's <s>data</s>text segment. Then your assignment of it to the pointer assigns the address of its location in the data segment to the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

`"abcdefghijk"` is a string constant, and `p="abcdefghijk";` will give to `p` adress of this string. 
So it's normal that `printf("%s",p);` display this string without error.